# Collection view doesn't start at index 0 when loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've a collectionview that I use as an image gallery, its cell fill all its size and there's only an imageview inside it for each row.
I load its datasource as follow:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageSliderCell", for: indexPath) as! SliderCell

    // Configure the cell
    let url = URL(string: ad.images![indexPath.row].small_url!)
    cell.image.kf.setImage(with: url)

    return cell
}
```

The problem is: sometimes when the collectionview finish loading it starts displaying the first photo in the array(as it should works) but other times it starts from a different index, starting for example from the third photo as if I use something like collectionview.scrolltoindex(3).

Comment: I guess that "kf" is for KingFisher? Does KingFisher remove the current image before applying the on fetching the one that URL? Else, before ` cell.image.kf.setImage(with: url)` write `cell.image = nil` because cells are reused.

Comment: how are you setting the cell size?